# Doctrine Same query, getResult vs getArrayResult returning different results

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Building the following query:

```
$q = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select('a')
    ->where('a.account = :accountId')
    ->andWhere('a.organization = :organization_id')
    ->setParameters(
        array(
            'accountId' => $account_id,
            'organization_id' => $organization_id,
        )
    )
    ->getQuery();
```

When calling getResult() (and counting the result set):  `$attributes = count($q->getResult());` The result is 1 row returned (which is incorrect).

But, when calling getResultArray `$attributes = count($q->getArrayResult());` The result is 2 (which is correct)

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE 'accountattribute' (
  'account_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'organization_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'dataKey' varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  'dataValue' text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  'updated' datetime NOT NULL,
  'created' datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('account_id','organization_id','dataKey'),
  KEY 'organization_id' ('organization_id'),
  CONSTRAINT 'accountattribute_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('account_id') REFERENCES 'accounts' ('id'),
  CONSTRAINT 'accountattribute_ibfk_2' FOREIGN KEY ('organization_id') REFERENCES 'organizations' ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Expected result:**

```
    [
    {
        data_key: "foo",
        data_key: "bar",
        updated: "2014-05-10T21:09:56+0000",
        created: "2014-05-10T21:09:56+0000",
        account: {
            id: 1,
            display_name: "Test Account",
            organization: {
                id: 1,
                display_name: "NAME"
            },
            active: true,
            deleted: false,
            updated: "2014-05-09T15:25:16+0000",
            created: "2014-05-09T15:25:16+0000"
        },
        organization: {
            id: 1,
            display_name: "NAME"
        },
    },
    {
        data_key: "nice",
        data_key: "ace",
        updated: "2014-05-11T01:04:43+0000",
        created: "2014-05-11T01:04:43+0000",
        account: {
            id: 1,
            display_name: "Test Account",
            organization: {
                id: 1,
                display_name: "NAME"
            },
            active: true,
            deleted: false,
            updated: "2014-05-09T15:25:16+0000",
            created: "2014-05-09T15:25:16+0000"
        },
        organization: {
            id: 1,
            display_name: "NAME"
        },
    }
]
```

**Actual Result (when using getResult)**

```
[
    {
        account: {
            id: 1,
            display_name: "Test Account",
            organization: {
                id: 1,
                display_name: "NAME"
            },
            active: true,
            deleted: false,
            updated: "2014-05-09T15:25:16+0000",
            created: "2014-05-09T15:25:16+0000"
        },
        organization: {
            id: 1,
            display_name: "NAME"
        },
        data_key: "foo",
        data_value: "bar",
        updated: "2014-05-10T21:09:56+0000",
        created: "2014-05-10T21:09:56+0000"
    }
]
```

**Actual Result (when using getArrayResult)**

```
[
    {
        account: {
            id: 1,
            display_name: "Test Account",
            organization: {
                id: 1,
                display_name: "NAME"
            },
            active: true,
            deleted: false,
            updated: "2014-05-09T15:25:16+0000",
            created: "2014-05-09T15:25:16+0000"
        },
        organization: {
            id: 1,
            display_name: "NAME"
        },
        data_key: "foo",
        data_value: "bar",
        updated: "2014-05-10T21:09:56+0000",
        created: "2014-05-10T21:09:56+0000"
    }
]
```

Comment: can you show mapping of your entities ?

Comment: Did you add data in the DB by hand? `getArrayResult` will not hydrate your entities so it will probably not verify the integrity of your data.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I did add the data by hand. When using `getResult` the result is hydrated with the correct values, but only the first result is returned. While when I use `getArrayResult` both results are returned. The issue is that `getResult` isn't returning both results as one would expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this link: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

> Query#getResult(): Retrieves a collection of objects. The result is
> either a plain collection of objects (pure) or an array where the
> objects are nested in the result rows (mixed).
>
> Query#getArrayResult(): Retrieves an array graph (a nested array) that
> is largely interchangeable with the object graph generated by
> Query#getResult() for read-only purposes.
>
> An array graph can differ from the corresponding object graph in certain scenarios due to the difference of the identity semantics between arrays and objects.

I think something on relation mapping caused this.

Comment: Here's the entities and their mappings: https://gist.github.com/mikeluby/1684174d1aa9c6451d74

Comment: I included the repository as well.